# silverlight web application prevent file access from webserver through url

Tags: silverlight

Hi Team,
                I have a silverlight WebApplication, it has a folder on webserver that download a document and store for clients to view. The issue I am facing is that eventhough windows authentication is enabled and directory browesing is disabled. I am able to access and view the image using the url i.e. (http:\loclahost\webapp\dir\image1.tif) form a different domain.Is there some configuration I can do on web server (IIS 8) or I need to adopt some encryption logic in my code.

Any suggestion or help on this would be of gr8 help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's what I'm thinking, You must set permissions to IISUSRS (a system user created for ISS) to write and read your folder.

Comment: Windows authentication is enabled and it has appropriate permission. The issue herer is I am able to access the same from a different machine which is on a different domain and posses security risk for the documents.